# Flexbox not wrapping flex items

Tags: css

I'm trying to set up a layout for my site using flexbox **(inb4: I don't care about IE)** but for some reason the items aren't wrapping.

http://jsfiddle.net/EnUuA/

```
section { display:-webkit-flex; -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; width: 200px; /* ... */ }
div { -webkit-flex: 1; width:48%; /* ... */ }
```

​
I've tried setting a width in `px` and I've tried removing the width completely.. still doesn't wrap!

***So*, how can I get my flexboxes to wrap around in their container?**

*Please, before you answer, make sure that your answer actually uses the [flexible box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) and isn't just giving me block level elements.*

Comment: There is definitely a `display: -webkit-flex` . If I change it to `display: flex` [Chrome doesn't understand it.](http://i50.tinypic.com/2s9zt6t.png).

Comment: Safari < 7 uses the prefix: `display: -webkit-box;` http://jsfiddle.net/EnUuA/4/ It however looks like the wrap property has issues.

Comment: `display: -webkit-box;` is the old implementation of the flexbox. It's since been redone and is triggered by using `display: -webkit-flex;` http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/

Comment: Right, but the old implementation is  still the one applicable for Safari 5 and 6. Unless you use the flexie polyfill to enable the 2009 Flexbox model, you still have to use the old syntax for Safari in particular. That's what I wanted to point out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that (as of today) the `flex-flow` property is one that isn't in on Firefox (at least the CR 2012 version).

You can see the wrapping in this fiddle working in Opera/Chrome, however.

Safari Nightly also has it functioning http://nightly.webkit.org

[edit] stupid Compass forgot the prefixes

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/flex
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

**NB** as of FF 21.0a1 it does not support `flex-wrap`

At least you can validate the property works:

http://jsfiddle.net/M7yLn/1/

[image: Wrapping like a boss]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Can you put a link to a reference for the flex properties you're using? Specifically the `flex: 0 0 auto`? I found out, though, that iPad doesn't support `display: flex`, and instead only supports `display: box`. I will rephrase my question, and will mark yours as the answer once you put a reference. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure about a year ago, or a year from now - but as of today iOS7 still doesn't support `display: flex` but does support webkit prefixed css selectors eg. `display: -webkit-flex;` and `-webkit-flex-direction: column`