# Flex-wrap polyfill for Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, flexbox

According to [Mozilla's own documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Notes):

> Firefox supports only single-line flexbox.

However I would like to start using flexboxes since it's [mostly supported by all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) now (I don't need to target IE 9 for this project luckily).

Since Firefox only supports single-line flexbox, the only benefit I get out of using it is `justify-content` and possibly `align-items`. In my opinion, the real power of flexboxes is `flex-flow` and `flex-wrap`, which allows for responsive layouts.

Actually, I tried copying the [Holy Grail Layout example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Holy_Grail_Layout_example) from the Mozilla documentation and opening it in Firefox and it didn't even work properly there. The `order` changed but it still showed the three elements in one row instead of changing the `flex-flow`.

Related question: [Flexbox not wrapping flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389317/flexbox-not-wrapping-flex-items)

I am pretty sure that most of my target audience is on Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Safari for iOS. Is there a polyfill that I can use for Firefox to get the desired behaviour or do I have to fallback to `float`s, `width`s, and `clear`fixes using Modernizr (and if so, what do I even look for in Modernizr?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No polyfill needed any more**: `flex-wrap: wrap` for Firefox 28 and up is fixed, please see also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434481/css3-flexbox-doesnt-display-correctly-in-firefox-22/20495644#20495644).

**Fix for older browsers**: For the "[solved by flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/)" demos Philip Walton uses a simple CSS polyfill: `@supports not (flex-wrap: wrap)` is only targeting browsers with no support for `flex-wrap: wrap`, and as far as i understand it: `display: inline-block` is used instead.

Comment: The source link is broken, but thanks for `@supports not (flex-wrap: wrap)`

Answer (score 0):

This feature is nor ready yet on Firefox, as you already know. I haven't found any polyfill to flex-wrap yet. But I do know the precise enhancement issue for Firefox flex-wrap implementation.

Please, anyone wanting this feature should vote on the link below by adding yourself to the CC list:

[Firefox - Support multi-line flexbox (flex-wrap, align-content properties)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=702508)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `flex-direction:column;` instead of `flex-flow:column;`. Seems to be an error in Mozillas Holy Grail https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Holy_Grail_Layout_example